# Blank screen from the notification tab when the phone is locked - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When we double-tap a notification on the lock screen, it automatically prompts us to enter your mobile password, then upon unlocking the device, it launches the app **with blank screen** & then redirects to the data whichever notification was tapped.

I don't understand where the problem is happening? Is there anyone help me out with this problem?

**In case of Unlock Screen:** It is working perfectly.

**In case of Lock Screen:** It should have shown a **splash screen** instead of **blank screen**.